# Making SQL query to give specific results like this

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table called `dir` which has rows like:

```
field1   field2    filed 3
1        name      sam 
1        age       18
1        class     12
2        name      jolly
2        age       14
2        class     8
.        .         .
.        .         .
.        .         .
```

I want to display it as follows using my SQL query

```
no      name     age    class
1       sam      18     12
2       jolly    14     8
```

Comment: Use pivot for this see the example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server

Comment: That's why I consider EAV tables as anti-design. That's a pain to query

Comment: For a dynamic solution, instead consider handling this in application code.

Comment: One difficulty with a dynamic approach is getting the attributes (field2) to return in a meaningful order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select field1,
       max(case when field2 = 'name' then field3 end) as name,
       max(case when field2 = 'age' then field3 end) as age,
       max(case when field2 = 'class' then field3 end) as class
from t
group by field1;
```

Comment: Could this be dynamic ?

Comment: @Cid . . . Yes, it could be.  That would require dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation

```
select field1,max(case when field2='name' then field3 end) name,
max(case when field2='age' then field3 end) age,
max(case when field2='class' then field3 end) class
 from table group by field1
```